# Sitecore - Email Campaign manager: $fullname$ is not replaced on the online version

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

For my newsletter implementation, I have defined a text like this:

Hello $fullname$,

The variable is correctly replaced when the email is sent. The user will see his first name.
Inside the newsletter, the reader is allowed to read the newsletter online.
Via a link, he will be redirected to a web site.
On the online version, the variable is not replaced.

The user will read Hello $fullname$,

Is there something that should be configured / developped ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add sublayout called **Process Personalization Tokens** to the item Presentation.
Take a look at the standard module templates(like **One Column Message**) as an example.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I have associated in my Branch template (Newsletter/$name) -> Layout / Presentation / details. The Process Personalization Tokens linked to the placeholder using the sublayout on which there will be the token. Nothing change. When I click on the link to visualize my newsletter online, I can still see $fullname$

Comment: Is that the item which is displayed when you open a link from newsletter? 
Try to copy and then customize standard module branch.

Comment: The cause was about an incorrect placeholder name linked to the sub layout. I didn't use the placeholder key. I defined the placeholder name (and as I had the good idea to change the key .....) Thank you Alexander, your answer was the correct one.